# Guidance on creating a drawing / diagramming application in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, drawing

I need help on creating an application like Visio in Silverlight, of course a much more simpler one. Just dragging and dropping shapes and connecting them is enough at this time. Can someone direct me to some resources about this? Algorithms / implementations don't need to be in C# / Silverlight. It may be enough to start with the logic behind such an application.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774112/do-silverlight-apis-exist-for-diagramming ?

Comment: Not exactly but digital logic simulator might be a start for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1](http://livegeometry.codeplex.com/) This is a great drawing example--complex but worth exploring.